# Checking if the JDBC connection is writable; using preferredTestQuery or ConnectionTester

Tags: mysql, jdbc, c3p0

**Current setup:**

Service host (Java) connects to (JDBC) master DB (MySQL) and has a slave (read-only) for reliability

**Scenario:**

In case of flip, I need to upgrade slave to new master. Present master becomes read-only and new master is promoted to read-write. I am looking to automatically refresh the C3P0 connection pool to the new master using a test query (executing writable query to database).

**Idea:**

Exploring a way to auto refresh JDBC connection pool so that they connect to new master when there is a flip (present master would be RO and slave would be promoted to RW and master cname would be updated)

**Present config**

```
        <property name="driverClass" value="${DriverClass}" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${ReadWriteDatabaseURL}${AccountDatabaseName}${JDBCProperties}" />
        <property name="user" value="${ReadWriteDatabaseCredentials}.principal" />
        <property name="password" value="${ReadWriteDatabaseCredentials}.credential" />
        <property name="testConnectionOnCheckout" value="true"/>
        <property name="testConnectionOnCheckin" value="false" />
        <property name="preferredTestQuery" value="update existing_table set value = now() where id = 1;"/>
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="44000"/>
        <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="30"/>
        <property name="maxStatements" value="50"/>
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="3"/>
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="3"/>
        <property name="acquireIncrement" value="2"/>
        <property name="checkoutTimeout" value="15000"/>
        <property name="acquireRetryDelay" value="1000"/>
```

Having a **preferredTestQuery** as `select 1 from existing_table where 1 = 0` absolutely works without any issue

*Approach 1:*

In C3P0 config or hibernate config - Use preferredTestQuery as a writable query (something like insert/update an existing table) and have the query executed on every connection checkout (testConnectionCheckout = true).
Not sure if this is supposed to be a simple query to test if db is up, because

- Insert/update queries doesn't work. May be we need to [begin, commit transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26636754/java-sql-sqlexception-an-attempt-by-a-client-to-checkout-a-connection-has-timed) ?

  - Error: `org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper: An attempt by a client to checkout a Connection has timed out.`
- Multiple queries doesn't work. Something like `create table if not exists; insert into .. ; drop table ..;`

  - Error: `org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper: An attempt by a client to checkout a Connection has timed out.`

*Approach 2:*
https://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_connection_testing refers to *Advanced users may define any kind of Connection testing they wish, by implementing a ConnectionTester and supplying the fully qualified name of the class as connectionTesterClassName.* Neither I am sure how can this be done nor if it works for writable calls

Stack trace for above error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.2.Final.jar:4.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.2.Final.jar:4.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.2.Final.jar:4.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:221) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.2.Final.jar:4.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:157) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.2.Final.jar:4.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.connection(SessionImpl.java:550) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.2.Final.jar:4.2.2.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:450) ~[spring-orm-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: An attempt by a client to checkout a Connection has timed out.
    at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:118) ~[mchange-commons-java-0.2.10.jar:0.2.10]
    at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:77) ~[mchange-commons-java-0.2.10.jar:0.2.10]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:690) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.1.jar:0.9.5.1]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:140) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.1.jar:0.9.5.1]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.AbstractRoutingDataSource.getConnection(AbstractRoutingDataSource.java:164) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:141) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.2.Final.jar:4.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:292) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.2.Final.jar:4.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.2.Final.jar:4.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:157) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.2.Final.jar:4.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.connection(SessionImpl.java:550) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.2.Final.jar:4.2.2.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:450) ~[spring-orm-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
    ... 42 more
Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.TimeoutException: A client timed out while waiting to acquire a resource from com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@4c86da0c -- timeout at awaitAvailable()
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1467) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.1.jar:0.9.5.1]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:644) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.1.jar:0.9.5.1]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:554) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.1.jar:0.9.5.1]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutAndMarkConnectionInUse(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:758) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.1.jar:0.9.5.1]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:685) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.1.jar:0.9.5.1]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:140) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.1.jar:0.9.5.1]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.AbstractRoutingDataSource.getConnection(AbstractRoutingDataSource.java:164) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:141) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.2.Final.jar:4.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:292) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.2.Final.jar:4.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.2.Final.jar:4.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:157) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.2.Final.jar:4.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.connection(SessionImpl.java:550) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.2.Final.jar:4.2.2.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:450) ~[spring-orm-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
    ... 42 more
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comment on the larger failover issue, but you certainly can define a `ConnectionTester` that does basically anything you want.
See the [apidocs for the `UnifiedConnectionTester` interface](https://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/apidocs/com/mchange/v2/c3p0/UnifiedConnectionTester.html) for concise instructions.

`c3p0`'s built-in ConnectionTester uses `Statement.executeQuery(...)` so `INSERT`s etc may not work. Your custom `ConnectionTester` can do whatever it wants. You should be sure it does something sane if `preferredTestQuery` and `rootCauseOutParamHolder` are set `null` (in either method).

If you wish you may ignore `preferredTestQuery`, or require that it be null (ie throw an `Exception` if `preferredTestQuery` is set).

Comment: Yup, that's exactly the issue. Appreciate your help Steve, thanks. I was referring to your [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30211610/reasons-why-resources-in-c3p0-cannot-get-checked-out) over stackoverflow. and setting log level of `com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool` to debug found that `java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery().`

Comment: However, I wonder how it was working with `testConnectionOnCheckin` but not `testConnectionOnCheckout`
I was able to flip over to master and no issues when using testConnectionOnCheckin=true. However, table values are not updated if I use `testConnectionOnCheckin`. I wonder if `testConnectionOnCheckin` uses executeUpdate() ? or if it ignores errors, unsure how the data connection is reset to new master.

Comment: the tests are the same, whether on checkin or checkout. however, failures on checkin, while you should be able to get them into logs, will be much less visible in terms of application behavior.

Comment: if you use a "query" that `executeQuery` refuses, the when testing on checkout, you'll just always fail to get Connections. testing on checkin is asynchronous. your application won't see a problem, but under the covers c3p0 will be always destroying and reacquiring rather than reusing checked-in connections (that look broken).

Comment: in terms of failover, this might seem great, because the reacquisitions might always come from the latest master. but in terms of performance it won't be great. it'll still be better than naive Connection acquisition, because c3p0 will batch-acquire asynchronously. But you'll be churning through Connections, with whatever overhead that entails.

Comment: Awesome, that's pretty insightful. I now see why it works for checkin. Hence if I have checkin set to true in my code, it always fails and reacquires connections ? That's useful only during fail over but it is a big overhead on service.

Comment: i don't want to say for certain, because i'm not looking at your logs, but checkin tests should be failing, if checkout tests fail because your driver rejects your preferred test query in `executeQuery(...)`. it's the same test wherever you run it.

Comment: Awesome, :-) That's really helpful. Thanks Steve